# Add rectangle to map made with Cartopy python to select subspace

Tags: python, maps, cartopy

I have made the following map with Cartopy:

[image: MAP]

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-80, 40, 20, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines(resolution='50m', linewidth=.5, color='black') # add map
plt.show()
```

and I would lie to add a rectagle to indicate a subspace. The rectangle should cover the space lon = (-10,20) lat = (30,70).  The output should look sth like:

[image: Output]

Any idea?

[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swMVq.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `ax.plot()` command with proper options.

```
# (Relevant code only)
# You wont get straight lines, but great-circle arcs.
ax.plot([-10, 20, 20, -10, -10], [30, 30, 70, 70, 30],
         color='black', linewidth=1, marker='.',
         transform=ccrs.Geodetic(), #remove this line to get straight lines
         )
```

[image: square]

Answer (score 3):

This option might be helpful to others, as you can also set to facecolor and get straight lines.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-80, 40, 20, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines(resolution='50m', linewidth=.5, color='black') # add map

gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.4, color='k',
                  linestyle='--')
ax.add_patch(mpatches.Rectangle(xy=[-10, 30], width=30, height=40,
                                facecolor='none', edgecolor='k',
                                transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()))
plt.show()
```

[image]